# How does Salesforce handle incoming emails

Tags: email, email2case

We are looking at Salesforce and I have been doing the Trailhead to learn more about it. I see that there is a Email to Case option which is great. But we will have a web server in a different country and will need to have the data in our country only.

I have been told the user information will be stored in our country, is this the same with emails that are forwarded?

Other systems I have used in the past I know this would be stored on the webserver.

Thanks for any help or direction. I am not the Admin of salesforce.

Comment: Are you only talking about use of emails for creating and commenting on cases? If so, the email is simply used to either create a case or add a comment to an existing case and the email itself is not stored. Where the case data is held depends on where your Salesforce org's instance is located.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am talking about the Email-to-Case - Turn Customer Emails into Cases. That part of the Trailhead has me forwarding emails to an @Salesforce email address.

Comment: Those emails are converted into Cases or case comments and are otherwise discarded. Like I said, you can determine the location of your org by determining the instance it sits on. Look for instance info in the Company Information section in setup, then visit https://availability.salesforce.com/find-my-instance/

Comment: @PhilW - my experience is that those E2C emails are saved as EmailMessage objects as child of Case via ParentId lookup field

Comment: Ah! Forgot about that. Still, the important point is the location of the org's instance...

Comment: @PhilW Thank you, so that would mean that it would be stored in the other country.

Comment: You can probably ask Salesforce to migrate your org to a more appropriate instance. Contact your Account Executive or, if you don't have one, try raising a support case.

Comment: You have two systems at play here -- your mail server that receives the E2C email (e.g. Gmail, Outlook, ..) and after the mail server forwards the E2C email to SFDC, the [SFDC database](https://availability.salesforce.com/find-my-instance/). The email message will exist in both systems.

Comment: [Hyperforce](https://www.salesforce.com/eu/products/platform/hyperforce/) is your friend - talk to your account team.